# How to prevent player movement outside of given area map?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have created a 4x6 area map using a dictionary called zonemap. I have nested multiple dictionaries within that dictionary; each one representing an area a player can visit and interact with. I want to be able to restrict player movement to that 4x6 area, and also redisplay the location from where they tried to access the "forbidden" area. This restriction would only occur when the player tries to access areas marked by the empty string. Sample code below:

```
import cmd
import textwrap
import sys
import os
import time
import random

class player:
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = ''
        self.job = ''
        self.hp = 0
        self.mp = 0
        self.stamina = 0
        self.faith = 0
        self.status_effects = []
        self.location = "a2"
        self.gameOver = False
myPlayer = player()

ZONENAME = ''
DESCRIPTION = 'description'
EXAMINATION = 'examine'
SOLVED = False
UP = 'up', 'north'
DOWN = 'down', 'south'
LEFT = 'left', 'west'
RIGHT = 'right', 'east'

solved_places = {'a1': False, 'a2': False, # more places}

zonemap = {
    'a1': {
        ZONENAME: "West Mounatains",
        DESCRIPTION: "A mountain range.",
        EXAMINATION: "The slope is too steep to climb.",
        SOLVED: False,
        UP: '',
        DOWN: "Western Forest",
        LEFT: '', 
        RIGHT: "Central Mountains",
    },
    'a2': {
        ZONENAME: "Central Mountains",
        DESCRIPTION: "A mountain range",
        EXAMINATION: "These mountains go on for miles.",
        SOLVED: False,
        UP: '',
        DOWN: "Eastern Forest",
        LEFT: "Western Mountains",
        RIGHT: "Mountain Cave",
    },
    # more dictionaries
}

def prompt():
    print("\n" + "=========================")
    print("What would you like to do?")
    player_action = input("> ")
    acceptable_actions = ['move', 'go', 'travel', 'walk', 'quit', 'examine', 'inspect', 'interact', 'look']
    while player_action.lower() not in acceptable_actions:
        print("Unknown action, try again.\n")
        player_action = input("> ")
    if player_action.lower() == 'quit':
        sys.exit()
    elif player_action.lower() in ['move', 'go', 'travel', 'walk']:
        player_move(player_action.lower())
    elif player_action.lower() in ['examine', 'inspect', 'interact', 'look']:
        player_examine(player_action.lower())

def player_move(player_action):
    ask = "Where would you like to move?\n"
    dest = input(ask)
    if dest in ['up', 'north']:
        destination = zonemap[myPlayer.location][UP]
        movement_handler(destination)
    elif dest in ['down', 'south']:
        destination = zonemap[myPlayer.location][DOWN]
        movement_handler(destination)
    elif dest in ['left', 'west']:
        destination = zonemap[myPlayer.location][LEFT]
        movement_handler(destination)
    elif dest in ['right', 'east']:
        destination = zonemap[myPlayer.location][RIGHT]
        movement_handler(destination)

def movement_handler(destination):
    print("\n" + "You have moved to the " + destination + ".")
    myPlayer.location = destination
    print_location()
```

I'm thinking an if statement would work, but I don't know where to put it. Any help would be appreciated. I can also provide more code, if needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, an `if` would work. Check where the user wants to go to. **If** it is invalid, print a message and don't move the player. **Else** move them.

```
def player_move(player_action):
    ask = "Where would you like to move?\n"
    dest = input(ask).lower()
    if dest in ['up', 'north']:
        destination = UP
    elif dest in ['down', 'south']:
        destination = DOWN
    elif dest in ['left', 'west']:
        destination = LEFT
    elif dest in ['right', 'east']:
        destination = RIGHT
    else:
        print("Bad entry")
        return

    if "" == zonemap[myPlayer.location][destination]:
        print("Can't go there")
    else:
        movement_handler(zonemap[myPlayer.location][destination])
```

Comment: Thanks, Johnny. I'll try this out.

Answer (score 0):

Johnny's solution is correct, and probably a good solution if you're learning Python. In general though, long series of if/elif/elif/elif/else are difficult to maintain and often indicate that the code could be made simpler.

Allow me to demonstrate a few such issues..

Instead of checking for direction synonyms/aliases everywhere, you can define a function that coalesces all possible aliases to 4 directional values, e.g.:

```
def direction(whence):
    "define direction aliases"
    whence = whence.lower()
    return {
        'north': 'up',
        'east': 'right',
        'south': 'down',
        'west': 'left',
    }.get(whence, whence)
```

then you can get the desired direction by:

```
destination = direction(input("where would you like to go? "))
```

and your zones could be defined as:

```
'a2': {
    ... 
    'up': "", 
    'down': "Eastern Forrest",
    'left': "Western Mountains",
    'right': "Mountain Cave"
```

This particular problem is also a good fit for a more object-oriented approach. You've already defined a Player class, how about defining a Zone class?

First let's define some conveniences so we don't have to repeat ourselves so many times when setting up the zone map.

We know that left is the opposite direction of right etc., let's declare all opposites:

```
opposites = {
    'left': 'right',
    'up': 'down',
}
opposites.update({v: k for k, v in opposites.items()})
```

and we know that if you're at point A and move right to point B, then you can move left to get back to point A.  A descriptor class is a bit magical, but very useful:

```
class Path(object):
    "Descriptor class that sets both ends of a path."
    def __init__(self, direction):
        self.direction = direction

    def __get__(self, obj, objtype):
        return obj.neighbors[self.direction]

    def __set__(self, obj, val):
        obj.neighbors[self.direction] = val
        val.neighbors[opposites[self.direction]] = obj
```

Then the Zone class can be defined:

```
class Zone(object):
    up = Path('up')
    right = Path('right')
    down = Path('down')
    left = Path('left')

    def __init__(self, name, description='', examination=''):
        self.name = name
        self.description = description
        self.examination = examination
        self.neighbors = dict(
            up=None,
            right=None,
            down=None,
            left=None)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def valid_moves(self):
        return [direction
                for direction, target in self.neighbors.items()
                if target is not None]
```

and instead of indirectly stitching the map together in a dict, we can now define the relations directly:

```
def create_map():
    # create the zones as objects
    west_mountains = Zone('West Mountains')
    central_mountains = Zone('Central Mountains')
    eastern_forest = Zone('Eastern Forest')
    mountain_cave = Zone('Mountain Cave')
    western_forest = Zone('Western Forest')

    # connect the zones directly (the opposite direction is automagically
    # set by the Path descriptor class)
    west_mountains.down = western_forest     # western_forrest.up = west_mountains happens in Path descriptor
    west_mountains.right = central_mountains
    central_mountains.down = eastern_forest
    central_mountains.right = mountain_cave

    return central_mountains  # return starting position
```

moving the player should be a method on the Player class in an object-oriented design, so:

```
class Player(object):
    def __init__(self, name, location):
        self.name = name
        self.location = location

    def move(self, direction):
        if self.location.neighbors[direction] is None:
            raise ValueError("No such path")
        self.location = self.location.neighbors[direction]
```

then we can move around the map:

```
def play():
    starting_location = create_map()

    p = Player(
        name=input("what is your name? "),
        location=starting_location
    )

    while 1:
        where = input('Where would you like to move? ')
        if where.lower() in ('quit', 'q'):
            break
        try:
            p.move(direction(where))
            print("you're at: ", p.location)
        except ValueError as e:
            print(e)
            print("Valid directions are:", p.location.valid_moves())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    play()
```

sample session:

```
(dev) go|c:\srv\tmp> py3 mountains.py
what is your name? bjorn
Where would you like to move? North
No such path
Valid directions are: ['left', 'down', 'right']
Where would you like to move? West
you're at:  West Mountains
Where would you like to move? left
No such path
Valid directions are: ['down', 'right']
Where would you like to move? down
you're at:  Western Forest
Where would you like to move? South
No such path
Valid directions are: ['up']
Where would you like to move? north
you're at:  West Mountains
Where would you like to move? q
```

Comment: Thanks, thebjorn. I'll try Johnny's solution for now, as this is my first attempt at this type of game. I'll see about utilizing your solution in future iterations, though, as I like the usage.